# run a distribution test with jmeter in Vm Centos

Tags: centos, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to run a distribution test for learning purpose and i'm using a Virtual machine Centos 7 as a slave in my Windows 7 ( master running in window 7) but even if i configure the master with the IP of the slave ( VM ), modifying the file jmeter.properties, doesn't work, i try run Jmeter-server in the Centos machine but this problem appears.

```
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:44341](lo
cal),objID:[4e68a212:14a8564a618:-7fff, 5760053273490727502]]]
Server failed to start: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start. localhost.locald
omain is a loopback address.
An error occurred: Cannot start. localhost.localdomain is a loopback address.
```

Can somebody give me a direction where look or a explanation how can i do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the following line in *system.properties* file: `java.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
2. Alternatively start JMeter providing above property as a command-line argument as:

   ```
   jmeter (or jmeter-server) -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   ```
3. Double check your network configuration, i.e. make sure that your `/etc/hosts` file contains the following lines:

   ```
   127.0.0.1        localhost localhost.localdomain
   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  your CentOS machine hostname
   ```

In all above cases `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` should be IP address of your CentOS machine and this IP address must be different from 127.0.0.1.

Also make sure that you select "Bridged" networking in your Virtual Machine, machines should be able to reach each other over the network, firewalls should be properly configured to allow communication, etc.

For more information on different JMeter Properties and ways of setting/overriding them see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)